# Take fields and inner collection fields together

Tags: c#, linq

For example, I have class

```
public class Team
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string Location {get;set;}

   public List<Player> PList{get;set;}
}
```

And class Player

```
public class Player
{
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    public int Age {get;set;}
}
```

Please tell me, how should I perform a select from List of Team objects, to get new object:

```
public class TeamPlayer 
{
    public string TeamName {get;set;}
    public string TeamLocation {get;set;}
    public string PlayerFirstName {get;set;}
    public string PlayerFirstName {get;set;}
    public int PlayerAge {get;set;}
 }
```

For example I've got

```
 var TList = new List<Team>
{ 
  new Team() {
  Name = "Rostov",  
  Location  = "Rostov-on-Don", 
  PList = new List<Player>
  {
      new Player(){ FirstName = "Soslan", LastName = "Djanaev", Age = 28 },
      new Player(){ FirstName = "Christian", LastName = "Noboa", Age = 29 }
  } 
};
```

And I want TList  to become a List

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more please?

Comment: Could you explain what kind of new object you are talking.

Comment: I updated my question. Hope, it became more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

required selection can be performed with `SelectMany` method (query syntax is more compact)

```
var items = from a in aList
            from b in a.BList
            select new 
            {
                 Field1 = a.A1,
                 Field2 = a.A2,
                 Field3 = b.B1,
                 Field4 = b.B2,
                 Field5 = b.B3
            };
```